# Should the gained reputation for a tag wiki be reverted if the tag is removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

Today I came across a couple of wiki-edits that are useless given the fact that either the tag [hazlecast](/questions/tagged/hazlecast) was wrong, no questions existed for the tag [jquery-merge](/questions/tagged/jquery-merge) or the tag should be a synonym [vs2013](/questions/tagged/vs2013) [request for synonym here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215247/add-vs2013-as-a-synonym-of-visual-studio-2013)

I do know that orphaned tags get [soft deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62536/is-the-tag-wiki-retained-for-a-tag-that-gets-removed-for-having-no-entries) by the [magic of the script of 03:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/158100).

I did found [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142706/extra-conditions-for-gaining-reputation-from-editing-the-tag-wiki-once-created) that addresses the issue to gain reputation multiple times for editing the same tag.

Question:
Is the reputation gained from  *wiki's edits that only exist for less then 24 hours* reverted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the reputation gained from wiki's edits that only exist for less then 24 hours reverted?

No, it's not reverted which is indeed weird since reputation gained for suggested edit on a post that is deleted does get reverted. Guess it's because the tag wiki doesn't really disappear, just "orphaned".

Proof can be found in [this user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh?tab=reputation), look under Jan 6, 2014:

> [image]

See the item in rec circle? It gives +2 and leads to https://stackoverflow.com/q/20949878 which does not exist anymore (looks like the tag was synonomized with [cordova](/questions/tagged/cordova)). ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3738456) is the relevant suggested edit)